# play_audio function crash python chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat

Hi so I have a problem with a function in my python code

play_audio loads in the receive message function (notifcation) when I receive a message a crash occurs (no traceback)

The audio file is in the same directory and I suspect that

play_obj.wait_done()

Stops the thread

> ```
> import socket
> import threading
> import simpleaudio as sa
>
> def play_audio(file_path):
>     wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(file_path)
>     play_obj = wave_obj.play()
>     play_obj.wait_done()  
>
>
> def receive_messages():
>     while True:
>         data = client_socket.recv(1024)
>         if not data:
>             print("Disconnected from server.")
>             break
>         print("Message received from server:", data.decode())
>         play_audio('darks-uwu-made-with-Voicemod.wav') 
>
> def send_message():
>     while True:
>         message = input("Enter your message: ")
>         client_socket.sendall(message.encode())
>
> client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> server_ip = 'xoxo25012008-61686.portmap.host'  # Remplacez par l'IP du serveur central
> server_port = 61686  # Port sur lequel le serveur central Ã©coute
> client_socket.connect((server_ip, server_port))
>
> receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages)
> send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_message)
>
> receive_thread.start()
> send_thread.start()
> ```

So first I tried to delete the play_audio function and its work but I wanted to keep it, then I deleted play_obj.wait_done()

And it crashes too

Thanks for any help